# Default behavior of pressing [ENTER] key on textbox on ASP.NET form is different between IE & Chrome/FF?

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I've made a little testing ASP.NET web application includes only default.aspx and target.aspx; on default.aspx I can input a name on textbox, then I can click Button or press ENTER key on textbox to submit the form.

I noticed that if I set the **UseSubmitBehavior** of button control to **True** (make the button rendered on browser as a "input type='submit" button), and I input name on text box then press ENTER key immediately, the default behavior would difference between IE and Chrome/FF: on IE, the server-side event handler Page_Load would be invoked but not Button1_Click; on Chrome/FF, both Page_Load and Button1_Click would be invoked; it seems a little tricky on Chrome/FF since I'd not click Button on the page, but it still invoked the server-side Button1_Click event handler? Did the default behavior of IE is submit the form directly, while Chrome/FF will try to find the first "input type='submit" element on form and call it's click method to perform submit action? The code of default.aspx is as following. Thanks a lot!

```
[default.aspx]
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="KeyEventTestWeb._default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
                    onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblIsPostBack" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


[default.aspx.cs]
namespace KeyEventTestWeb
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblIsPostBack.Text += "IsPostBack=" + IsPostBack.ToString() + 
                                  "<br>";
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblIsPostBack.Text += "Button1_Click()" + "<br>";
            Session["name"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Response.Redirect("target.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```